# Can I swap an LCD between different laptop generations?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, powerbook

I have a pair of old laptops:

- 15" PowerBook G4 (Aluminum) with various issues, but a working screen
- 15" MacBook Pro (2007) with a broken screen, but otherwise fine

Can the PowerBook screen be transplanted into the MacBook body? 
If so, does it require: Mac-specific tools? Additional parts? Custom driver? Soldering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the parts are not compatible nor are the cabling and mount points.

See http://ifixit.com for take apart manuals and possibly repair parts for your broken LCD on the MacBook Pro.